# value of selected item in dropdownlist on change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, onchange, html.dropdownlistfor

i have a dropdown list the values of dropdownlist is coming from database and i want just value of selected item on onchange ajax function but i don't get it kindly check and reply me as soon as possible. thanks

View :

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Company_Department.Company.Name, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company_Department.Company.ID, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CompanyList, new { @class = "form-control" , @id = "CompanyId", @onchange="GetCompanyName()"})
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Company_Department.Company.ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Ajax on same view :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#CompanyId").change(function GetCompanyName() {
            var CompanyID = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                data: {
                    CompanyID: CompanyId,
                },
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCompanyName", "Admin")',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        });
        });

</script>
```

controller :

```
public string GetCompanyName(int CompanyId)
    {
        Company company = new Company();
        string c = db.Companies.Where(m=>m.ID == CompanyId).ToString();
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Try data: {'CompanyID': CompanyId },

Comment: its does not work @sajanyamaha

Comment: _but i don't get it kindly check_ Did you actually check for any error messages in console? Does the ajax call work properly? Does the controller return the data successfully? Kindly debug your code and check and post where exactly you are stuck and narrow down your question as far as possible.

Comment: @shujaatali,  Is change function working fine ?

Comment: @shujaatali, try data: {
                    CompanyID: parseInt(CompanyId)
                },

Comment: Yes change function is call i use alert after ajax its work @UmeshSehta

Comment: thanks @UmeshSehta its work but after change item in dropdownlist its go to error alert ,

im changing my code in controller now code is :
public string GetCompanyName(int CompanyId)
    {
        return CompanyId.ToString();
    }